# Python `functools.wraps` doesn't deal with defaults correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

When using `functools.wraps`, the signature claims one set of defaults, but the (wrapped) function uses the original (wrappee) defaults.

**Why is that a good thing?**

```py
from functools import wraps
from inspect import signature

def g(a: float, b=10):
    return a * b

def f(a: int, b=1):
    return a * b

assert f(3) == 3

f = wraps(g)(f)

assert str(signature(f)) == '(a: float, b=10)'  # signature says that b defaults to 10
assert f.__defaults__ == (1,)  # ... but it's a lie!
assert f(3) == 3 != g(3) == 30  # ... and one that can lead to problems!
```

Why is this so? Because `functools.wraps` updates the `__signature__` (including annotations and defaults), `__annotations__`, but not `__defaults__`, which python apparently looks to in order to assign defaults.

One solution is to politely ask wraps to include these defaults.

```py
from functools import wraps, WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS, partial

my_wraps = partial(wraps, assigned=(list(WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS) + ['__defaults__', '__kwdefaults__']))

def g(a: float, b=10):
    return a * b

def f(a: int, b=1):
    return a * b

assert f(3) == 3

f = my_wraps(g)(f)

assert f(3) == 30 == g(3)
assert f.__defaults__ == (10,)  # ... because now got g defaults!
```

But why oh why don't I get that for free? When would I ever want the defaults that are actually used be different than those mentioned in the signature?!?

Comment: See https://hynek.me/articles/decorators/ section "Mangled Signatures". As is often the case in Python, there are better 3rd-party options than stdlib here.

Comment: First time I've ever seen anyone on SO reluctant to jump to the conclusion that they have discovered a bug in Python!

Comment: @kindall but this kinda does seem like a bug to me. I may be missing something but I think OP could reasonably report this to bugs.python.org. Maybe there's a good reason for it or maybe it's too late to change, but they could give the best answer.

Comment: @AlexHall: I could agree with you, but not sure where the masses decided the "bug" threshold lies. All I can say here is that when I use `wraps` out of the box, it misaligns actual defaults and what the signature says the defaults are. My question: Is there a good reason for this, or was it just overlook.

Comment: @thorwhalen you're not being crushed or bullied there, you're being asked plainly for context. That question and some comments there are written confusingly, conflating the standard wraps with your own version.

Comment: @AlexHall I concur. It definitely seems like a bug to me, and I'd report it post haste.

Comment: Done. Thanks guys/gals.